# How can I download db from heroku?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, mysql, heroku-postgres

I'm using heroku and I want to download the database from my app(heroku) so I can make some changes in it, I've installed pgbackups, but using `heroku pgbackups:url` downloads a .dump file

How can I download a postgresql file or translate that .dump into a postgresql file?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you're using Heroku's pgbackups (which you probably should be using):

```
$ heroku pg:backups capture
$ curl -o latest.dump `heroku pg:backups public-url`
```

"Translate" it into a postgres db with

```
$ pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser -d mydb latest.dump
```

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

Comment: pgbackups do not exist any longer, now it seems to be pg:backups. And there is no pg:backups:url.

Comment: The first two commands are apparently verbatim, but in the third, I had to replace `myuser` with my Postgres username and `mydb` with the name of the database I wanted to transcribe the data into.

Answer (score 14):

There's a command for this in the CLI - `heroku db:pull` which will do this for you. `db:pull` can be a bit slow mind you so you may be better to use the next option.

If you are using complex postgress data types (hstore, arrays etc) then you need to use the pgtransfer plugin https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-pg-transfer which will basically does a backup on Heroku and a restores it locally.

UPDATE: `db:pull` and `db:push` have been deprecated and should be replaced with `pg:pull` and `pg:push` - read more at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-push-and-pg-pull

Answer (score 7):

I found the first method suggested in the [documentation pull/push](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-push-and-pg-pull) even easier. No password or username needed.

> pg:pull
>
> pg:pull can be used to pull remote data from a Heroku Postgres
>   database to a database on your local machine. The command looks like
>   this:
>
> `$ heroku pg:pull HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA mylocaldb --app sushi`
>
> This command will create a new local database named “mylocaldb” and
>   then pull data from database at `DATABASE_URL` from the app “sushi”. In
>   order to prevent accidental data overwrites and loss, the local
>   database must not exist. You will be prompted to drop an already
>   existing local database before proceeding.

At first I had an error: `/bin/sh: createdb: command not found`; which I solved following [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32532876/5802289).

---

An alternative described also in the documentation (I did not try it yet) is:

> To export the data from your Heroku Postgres database, create a new
>   backup and download it.
>
> ```
> $ heroku pg:backups:capture
>
> $ heroku pg:backups:download
> ```

*Source: [Importing and Exporting Heroku Postgres Databases with PG Backups](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export)*

Answer (score 4):

To export the data from Heroku Postgres database, just follow below steps

1. Login to heroku
2. Go to APP->settings->reveal config variable
3. Copy DATABASE_URL
4. run `pg_dump --DATABASE_URL_COPIED_IN_STEP_3 > database_dump_file`

Note this will provide postgresql file or for dump file you can download directly from postgres addon interface.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to download and replicate the database on local server:

```
 **PGUSER**=LOCAL_USER_NAME PGPASSWORD=LOCAL_PASSWORD heroku pg:pull --app APP_NAME HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_DB_NAME LOCAL_DB_NAME
```

Go through this document for more info:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-push-and-pg-pull

Answer (score 0):

This is the script that I like to use.

```
namespace :heroku do

  desc "Import most recent database dump"
  task :import_from_prod => :environment do
    puts 'heroku run pg:backups capture --app APPNAME'
    restore_backup 'APPNAME'
  end

  def path_to_heroku
    ['/usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku', '/usr/local/bin/heroku'].detect {|path| File.exists?(path)}
  end

  def heroku(command, site)
    `GEM_HOME='' BUNDLE_GEMFILE='' GEM_PATH='' RUBYOPT='' #{path_to_heroku} #{command} -a #{site}`
  end

  def restore_backup(site = 'APPNAME')
    dump_file = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/postgres.dump"
    unless File.exists?(dump_file)
      pgbackups_url = heroku('pg:backups public-url -q', site).chomp
      puts "curl -o #{dump_file} #{pgbackups_url}"
      system "curl -o #{dump_file} '#{pgbackups_url}'"
    end
    database_config = YAML.load(File.open("#{Rails.root}/config/database.yml")).with_indifferent_access
    dev_db = database_config[Rails.env]
    system "pg_restore -d #{dev_db[:database]} -c #{dump_file}".gsub(/\s+/,' ')
    puts
    puts "'rm #{dump_file}' to redownload postgres dump."
    puts "Done!"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For me a simple `heroku pg:pull DATABASE local-db-name -a app-name` worked.

Warning: I do mean just the word "DATABASE", not the name of the database or anything fancy. If you run `rake db:drop` right before, it will display your local database name, which should be something like `ABC_development`.

Answer (score 0):

#### To create a backup

As of 2024, this command will [default to your primary database](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#manual-backups):

```bash
heroku pg:backups:capture
```

it will output something like this

```
heroku pg:backups:capture
Starting backup of postgresql-octagonal-77143... done

Use Ctrl-C at any time to stop monitoring progress; the backup will continue running.
Use heroku pg:backups:info to check progress.
Stop a running backup with heroku pg:backups:cancel.

Backing up DATABASE to b002... done
```

Note the `b002` on the last line (you'll use it in the next step)

#### To download it

To [download](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#download-via-a-url) the backup you just created (replace `b002` with the token you got from the step above):

```bash
heroku pg:backups:url b002
The following URL will expire at 2015-04-07 18:35:50 +0000:
"http://s3.amazonaws.com/xkpgbackups/app1234567@heroku.com/b004.dump?AWSAccessKeyId=ABCD1234&Expires=1289261668&Signature=3mMBeKISewgEUDT%2FL5mRz4EYS4M%3D"
```

Note (from heroku docs):

> The URL is public but not easily guessable. It expires after 60 minutes.

#### To use the database backup/dump in your development environment

```bash
# drop your local (test and development) databases
rails db:drop

# create your local (test and development) databases
rails db:create

# restore your heroku backup into the local/development database
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -d yourappname_development -U steve ~/Downloads/78F1545c-9f03-45ec-8ad9-58106e186cd7
```

- To get the value for `yourappname_development` replace `yourappname` with your actual app's name (leave the `_development` bit
- If you're using the rails 7 default database.yml file, then your username will be found by going into the terminal and typing `whoami`, replace it with yours above `-U steve`
- replace `~/Downloads/78F1545c-9f03-45ec-8ad9-58106e186cd7` with the database backup you downloaded