# Heroku pg:pull is giving sh: createdb: command not found

Tags: postgresql, heroku, pgadmin

When I try to do `heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL myappspassword`, I get this error:

```
my-computer:a-folder (master*) · heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL myappspassword
 !    sh: createdb: command not found
 !    
 !    Unable to create new local database. Ensure your local Postgres is working and try again.
```

For once Googling doesn't return a result. I'm wondering if it's related to the fact that when I do `which psql`, there is no result. Maybe I need to do something special with pgAdmin to get this working (e.g. export command line tools)?

Answer (score 14):

Are you on a Mac, by chance, and using [Postgres App](http://postgresapp.com/)?

If so, the problem might be that `createdb` isn't on your path. Try adding it by inserting the following into `~/.bash_profile`.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin
```

Then run `source ~/.bash_profile` and try again.

There's more info on the Postgres App site: http://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html

Comment: Perfect! And [here is how to modify `~/.bash_profile`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30462883/5802289). Note that the version number might have to be adapted depending on the local version installed. Obvious, but I missed it at first.

Answer (score 2):

Your instincts are correct. You need to be able to access the Postgres from your command line. `pg:pull` is attempting to create a new local database and drop the relevant data from your Heroku database into it. [From the docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-push-and-pg-pull):

> This command will create a new local database named “mylocaldb” and then pull data from database at DATABASE_URL...

Basically, your local machine is trying to run `createdb` locally but your terminal isn't recognizing it.

Answer (score 1):

I battled this damn error for a few hours.  I can't say for certain if this will work for everyone but I found my issue stemmed from running the command via iTerm/ZSH instead of just normal bash.  I opened up plain-old vanilla terminal, ran the command, and everything fired off like it should.